# UWP Editing Style for 3rd state of AppBarToggleButton

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, styling, togglebutton

**AppBarToggleButton** has a property called "IsThreeState" which makes it possible to bind with a nullable boolean property **bool?** just like checkbox and toggle buttons have **IsIndeterminate** property for same purpose.

I was editing the style for AppBarToggleButton after borrowing base style for "generic.xaml" and I found no way to edit the style of this 3rd state when **IsChecked="{x:Null}"** there is no Visual State called "IsThreeState" or anything like that, unlike **togglebutton and checkbox** who have dedicated Visual States for "Indeterminate". How can I edit the style for this third state?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I edit the style for this third state?

You description is correct, `AppBarToggleButton` has no such  Indeterminate visual states. So we can't edit the style for this third state. But we can get the state name when AppBarToggleButton turn into third state. We could listen `CurrentStateChanging for` VisualStateGroup` and print current state name.

```
private void AppBarToggleButton_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

    IList<VisualStateGroup> list = VisualStateManager.GetVisualStateGroups(VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(sender as AppBarToggleButton, 0) as FrameworkElement);
    foreach (var v in list)
        if (v.Name == "CommonStates")
        {

            v.CurrentStateChanging += StateGroup1_CurrentStateChanging;

        }

}
private void StateGroup1_CurrentStateChanging(object sender, VisualStateChangedEventArgs e)
{
    Debug.WriteLine($"{e.OldState.Name}-{e.NewState.Name}");
}
```

We could find the matched visualstate for third state is `CheckedPointerOver`, we could edit it for this third state. Unfortunately, it only works for click behavior,  it will not response `IsChecked="{x:Null}"`.

```
<VisualState x:Name="CheckedPointerOver">
    <VisualState.Setters>
        <Setter Target="Root.(RevealBrush.State)" Value="PointerOver" />
        <Setter Target="ContentRoot.BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarToggleButtonRevealBorderBrushCheckedPointerOver}" />
        <Setter Target="Content.Foreground" Value="Yellow" />
        <Setter Target="TextLabel.Foreground" Value="Red" />
        <Setter Target="OverflowCheckGlyph.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarToggleButtonCheckGlyphForegroundCheckedPointerOver}" />
        <Setter Target="AccentOverlayBackground.Fill" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarToggleButtonRevealBackgroundHighLightOverlayCheckedPointerOver}" />
        <Setter Target="CheckedHighlightBackground.Fill" Value="Orange" />
        <Setter Target="OverflowTextLabel.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarToggleButtonOverflowLabelForegroundCheckedPointerOver}" />
        <Setter Target="KeyboardAcceleratorTextLabel.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarToggleButtonKeyboardAcceleratorTextForegroundCheckedPointerOver}" />
        <Setter Target="CheckedHighlightBackground.Opacity" Value="1" />
        <Setter Target="OverflowCheckGlyph.Opacity" Value="1" />
    </VisualState.Setters>
</VisualState>
```

So we suggest you use ToggleButton to replace AppBarToggleButton.

Comment: yeah I tried a lot of stuff with state changing and registering multiple property call backs to isChecked and other properties, I got it working as I intended but still couldnt make the 3rd state work properly in overflow mode, I added all new states in xaml and called them with GoToState() eventually I gave up and now just using a custom styles checkbox.